# Django admin.py readonly_fields not working

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I need to show on Django administration the date the object was created, but date field should be disabled of modification.

here is my model on Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_of_creation = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
```

here is my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('date_of_creation',)

admin.site.register(MyModel)
```

The "save() override to set the date of creation" isn't the case here.

I tried [this snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/937/) and [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) already, but can't find my mistake.

Please note that I'm a beginner in Django, and this is my first App.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register the admin class as well as the model.

```
admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Comment: Gosh... Thank you, can believe it was this, I feel ashamed.